# Finding area of rhombus

Tags: geometry, triangles

I’m trying to solve the following question but I’ve stuck.

AFAI find by using a property that opposite sides are congruent in a rhombus, angles of DAC, DCA, BAC, and BCA are equal each other.

[image]

Comment: This is not a rhombus..

Comment: @user289143 why? Don’t bother with drawing.

Comment: A rhombus must have the diagonals perpendicular

Comment: @user289143 drawing diagonals and putting right angles between them are possible. The fact that it isn’t given in this question doesn’t mean that it is not rhombus.The question says it is a rhombus.

Comment: Why do you think $\angle ADC = \angle DAC$?

Comment: @mjw fixed, my mistake.

Comment: @concurrencyboy so this picture is not faithful and doesn't represent the problem

Comment: @user289143 I’ve added the original question’s picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since AMD is a right triangle you have that the square of the length of a cathetus equals the product of the lengths of its orthographic projection on the hypotenuse times the length of this, i.e. if we denote with $K$ the midpoint of $AC$, we have $AD^2=AM \cdot AK$, so $AD^2=41 \cdot \frac{41+9}{2}=41 \cdot 25$. Now we can use Pythagoras' theorem on the triangle $ADK$ (it's a right triangle since $ABCD$ rhombus) and $DK^2=AD^2-AK^2=41 \cdot 25- 25^2=(41-25)\cdot 25=16 \cdot 25$, therefore $DK=4 \cdot 5=20$. Now we have everything since the area will be 
$$ DK \cdot AC=20 \cdot 50=1000$$[image]

Comment: +1 I knew I should have waited for a nice geometric solution before deploying trigonometry. Few people here know the word "cathetus". Now I do.

Comment: To be able to say $A^2=⋅$, shouldn’t be $AK$ has right angle with the base $AC$?

Comment: @EthanBolker either leg of right angle = cathetus

Comment: @concurrencyboy you mean $DK \perp AM$? (or equivalently $DK \perp AC$) It's true because $ABCD$ is a rhombus and therefore diagonals are perpendicular and meet each other in their midpoint

Comment: @user289143 yes, I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 1:

[image]

$$ AM.MC= MB^2,\, AB^2 =AM.AC $$

BM (red) is perpendicular bisector of AD

$$ AB=L = 5 \sqrt{41} $$

$$ \sin \theta = \dfrac{20}{5 \sqrt{41}}$$

If each side has length L and vertices have angles $( \theta , \pi- \theta ) $ then total area is

$$  L^2   \sin 2 \theta =1000 $$

etc..

Comment: I understand the explanations before the edit. I don’t get where/how $^2sin$ is obtained.

Comment: Apology. Typo after change of symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. Let $L$ be the side length, $T$ the length of $MD$ and $\alpha$ angle $MAD$. Then
$$
T = L \tan \alpha = 41 \cos \alpha
$$
$$
T^2 = 9^2 + L^2 = 18L \cos \alpha .
$$
That should provide sufficient information to find $L$, $T$ and $\alpha$. There's probably an algebraic shortcut that finds the area directly without needing the separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar triangles and the rest is just Pythagoras.
[image]

Comment: in your first saying(similarity of triangles) is there a wrong? tri. $ADM$ is similar to $tri. DOM$, not $ODM$? If not, what could you explain?